# Arch Linux installation error

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I'm trying to install Arch Linux, and have successfully connected to the internet via wifi. I'm also able to ping servers, but when trying to install the base system from `pacstrap /mnt base`, I'm getting: `error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from......` I have even tried a wired connection, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have IPv6 enabled?
Have you tried traceroute archlinux.org?

Answer (score 1):

You problably have outdated mirrors. 
Try update them from https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/ or download latest iso from https://www.archlinux.org/download/.
Other cause could be DNS problem. Can you ping servers by their names?

Comment: I've used the lates feb iso and yes I can ping servers